# Syntax for forcing a FOP debug mode in ant script

Tags: ant, apache-fop

I'm trying to troubleshoot a fop problem and I'm thinking that going from the default logging to debug might help. The fop doc says that I need to pass messagelevel="debug", but every variation of the syntax in my ant script fails.  I know this is more of an ant question, but I'm wondering is anyone has run into this.  Here's my non-working code:

```
  <macrodef name="fop">
    <attribute name="in" />
    <attribute name="out" />
    <sequential>
      <java classname="org.apache.fop.cli.Main" fork="true"
      failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-fo @{in}" />
        <arg line="-pdf @{out} messagelevel="debug" />
        <arg line="-c ${FopConfig}" />
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${FopBuild}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopAvalon}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopBatik}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopCommonsIo}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopCommonsLogging}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopFopHyph}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopJaiCodec}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopJaiCore}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopSerializer}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXalan}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXerces}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlApis}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlApisExt}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlGraphics}" />
        </classpath>
      </java>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

I've also tried this, with the arg as a separate line:

  <macrodef name="fop">
    <attribute name="in" />
    <attribute name="out" />
    <sequential>
      <java classname="org.apache.fop.cli.Main" fork="true"
      failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-fo @{in}" />
        <arg line="-pdf @{out} />
        <arg line"messagelevel="debug"" />
        <arg line="-c ${FopConfig}" />
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${FopBuild}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopAvalon}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopBatik}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopCommonsIo}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopCommonsLogging}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopFopHyph}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopJaiCodec}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopJaiCore}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopSerializer}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXalan}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXerces}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlApis}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlApisExt}" />
          <pathelement location="${FopXmlGraphics}" />
        </classpath>
      </java>
    </sequential>
  </macrodef>

I'm sure I'm not seeing something simple.
```

Comment: When you say your different attempts all failed, what does that mean? Describe the error messages or undesirable behavior you saw.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the double quotes (`"`) with `&quot;`:

```
<arg line="messagelevel=&quot;debug&quot;" />
```

It seems there is already an [Ant task](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/anttask.html) for the purpose of calling FOP. Any reason why you're not using it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks - your syntax change let me pass that string to the fop processor, which told me that "messagelevel="debug"" is meaningless, but it did spit out the whole usage help file. It turns out that debug mode is invoked with "-d". Anyways, here's the whole usage help text for anybody else:

```
FOP USAGE
fop [options] [-fo|-xml] infile [-xsl file] [-awt|-pdf|-mif|-rtf|-tiff|-png|-pcl|-ps|-txt|-at [mime]|-print] <outfile>
[OPTIONS]  
 -version          print FOP version and exit
 -d                debug mode   
 -x                dump configuration settings  
 -q                quiet mode  
 -c cfg.xml        use additional configuration file cfg.xml
 -l lang           the language to use for user information 
 -nocs             disable complex script features
 -r                relaxed/less strict validation (where available)
 -dpi xxx          target resolution in dots per inch (dpi) where xxx is a number
 -s                for area tree XML, down to block areas only
 -v                run in verbose mode (currently simply print FOP version and continue)

 -o [password]     PDF file will be encrypted with option owner password
 -u [password]     PDF file will be encrypted with option user password
 -noprint          PDF file will be encrypted without printing permission
 -nocopy           PDF file will be encrypted without copy content permission
 -noedit           PDF file will be encrypted without edit content permission
 -noannotations    PDF file will be encrypted without edit annotation permission
 -nofillinforms    PDF file will be encrypted without fill in interactive form fields permission
 -noaccesscontent  PDF file will be encrypted without extract text and graphics permission
 -noassembledoc    PDF file will be encrypted without assemble the document permission
 -noprinthq        PDF file will be encrypted without print high quality permission
 -a                enables accessibility features (Tagged PDF etc., default off)
 -pdfprofile prof  PDF file will be generated with the specified profile
                   (Examples for prof: PDF/A-1b or PDF/X-3:2003)

 -conserve         enable memory-conservation policy (trades memory-consumption for disk I/O)
                   (Note: currently only influences whether the area tree is serialized.)

 -cache            specifies a file/directory path location for the font cache file
 -flush            flushes the current font cache file

[INPUT]  
 infile            xsl:fo input file (the same as the next) 
                   (use '-' for infile to pipe input from stdin)
 -fo  infile       xsl:fo input file  
 -xml infile       xml input file, must be used together with -xsl 
 -atin infile      area tree input file 
 -ifin infile      intermediate format input file 
 -imagein infile   image input file (piping through stdin not supported)
 -xsl stylesheet   xslt stylesheet 

 -param name value <value> to use for parameter <name> in xslt stylesheet
                   (repeat '-param name value' for each parameter)

 -catalog          use catalog resolver for input XML and XSLT files
[OUTPUT] 
 outfile           input will be rendered as PDF into outfile
                   (use '-' for outfile to pipe output to stdout)
 -pdf outfile      input will be rendered as PDF (outfile req'd)
 -pdfa1b outfile   input will be rendered as PDF/A-1b compliant PDF
                   (outfile req'd, same as "-pdf outfile -pdfprofile PDF/A-1b")
 -awt              input will be displayed on screen 
 -rtf outfile      input will be rendered as RTF (outfile req'd)
 -pcl outfile      input will be rendered as PCL (outfile req'd) 
 -ps outfile       input will be rendered as PostScript (outfile req'd) 
 -afp outfile      input will be rendered as AFP (outfile req'd)
 -tiff outfile     input will be rendered as TIFF (outfile req'd)
 -png outfile      input will be rendered as PNG (outfile req'd)
 -txt outfile      input will be rendered as plain text (outfile req'd) 
 -at [mime] out    representation of area tree as XML (outfile req'd) 
                   specify optional mime output to allow the AT to be converted
                   to final format later
 -if [mime] out    representation of document in intermediate format XML (outfile req'd)
                   specify optional mime output to allow the IF to be converted
                   to final format later
 -print            input file will be rendered and sent to the printer 
                   see options with "-print help" 
 -out mime outfile input will be rendered using the given MIME type
                   (outfile req'd) Example: "-out application/pdf D:\out.pdf"
                   (Tip: "-out list" prints the list of supported MIME types and exits)
 -svg outfile      input will be rendered as an SVG slides file (outfile req'd) 
                   Experimental feature - requires additional fop-sandbox.jar.

 -foout outfile    input will only be XSL transformed. The intermediate 
                   XSL-FO file is saved and no rendering is performed. 
                   (Only available if you use -xml and -xsl parameters)


[Examples]
 fop foo.fo foo.pdf 
 fop -fo foo.fo -pdf foo.pdf (does the same as the previous line)
 fop -xml foo.xml -xsl foo.xsl -pdf foo.pdf
 fop -xml foo.xml -xsl foo.xsl -foout foo.fo
 fop -xml - -xsl foo.xsl -pdf -
 fop foo.fo -mif foo.mif
 fop foo.fo -rtf foo.rtf
 fop foo.fo -print
 fop foo.fo -awt
```